# Can't recursively call function in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, recursion, delegates

As a little program to get to know the language a bit I tried to implement the linq `Select` method (Commonly known as Map outside of .net) in VB, however it seems I've run into a small problem, it won't let me call the function recursively, because it thinks the types don't match

here's the code:

```
Iterator Function Map(Of A, B)(fun As Func(Of A, B), input As List(Of A)) As IEnumerable(Of B)
    If input Is Nothing Then
        Yield Nothing
    Else
        Yield fun(Head(input))
        Map(fun, Tail(input)) ' error here
    End If
End Function
```

Note here that `Head()` is a function that returns the first element of the input list, and `Tail()` is a method that returns everything BUT the first element

I did a test earlier to see if it was possible for me to pass a `Func(Of A, B)` into a function like I do here; it worked fine, so why it doesn't work now I don't really know...

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that `Head` and `Tail` have the following signatures:

```
Function Head(Of T)(lst As IEnumerable(Of T)) As T
    ...
End Function

Function Tail(Of T)(lst As IEnumerable(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    ...
End Function
```

then the line in question yields the following error (Hint: Always include the error message in your SO question.):

> Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in method 'Public Iterator Function Map(Of A, B)(fun As System.Func(Of A, B), input As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of A)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of B)' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.

So let's do what the error message asks:

```
Iterator Function Map(Of A, B)(fun As Func(Of A, B), input As List(Of A)) As IEnumerable(Of B)
    ...
        Map(Of A, B)(fun, Tail(input))
    ...
End Function
```

And we receive a more specific error:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of A)' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of A)'.

This makes sense: `Tail` returns an `IEnumerable`, `Map` requires a `List`. Since `Map` does not use any List-specific properties, let's just make `Map` more liberal in its input:

```
Iterator Function Map(Of A, B)(fun As Func(Of A, B), input As IEnumerable(Of A)) As IEnumerable(Of B)
    ...
End Function
```

Now, everything compiles correctly. In fact, we can now *remove* `(Of A, B)` again, because fixing the data type allowed VB.NET to correctly infer the required generic type parameters:

```
Iterator Function Map(Of A, B)(fun As Func(Of A, B), input As IEnumerable(Of A)) As IEnumerable(Of B)
    If input Is Nothing Then
        Yield Nothing
    Else
        Yield fun(Head(input))
        Map(fun, Tail(input)) ' works
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I'm so used to implicit conversions that I completely overlooked this... thanks.. Also way to go on exactly guessing the signatures of head and tail!

Comment: Tell me something, why is it that the function only returns a single element, rather than a whole collection?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee: Because you ignore the return value of `Map`. A simple solution would be `For v In Map(fun, Tail(input)): Yield v: Next`. Another solution would be not to use an iterator function but rather a regular function and `Return func(Head(input)).Concat(Map(fun, Tail(input)))`.

Comment: yeah I noticed that after I asked you, I'm just so used to recursive list building that I forgot Yield only works in loops, derp. thanks anyway